# Describe function not waiting until async done in Jasmine Javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm handling asynchronous code in Jasmine using done. Its function is waiting until `beforeAll` is done but describe function is not waiting...

Here is my code.

```
describe("xyz", function(){
var d;     
     beforeAll(function(done){
       $.getJSON( "path/abc.json", function( data ) {
         d = data;
         done();
       });
     });
     describe("some scenario", function(){
         // d value is undefined here 
         it("spec1", function(){ 
         // it is waiting until beforeAll function is done        
          expect().toBe();
        });
        it("spec2", function(){

          expect().toBe();
        });

        });
     });

     describe("scenario 2", function(){
        it("spec3", function(){
          expect().toBe();
        });
        it("spec 4", function(){
          expect().toBeGreaterThan();
        });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to imagine how the tests are run.

First run describe functions, which create test suites. 
Inside suite are functions (beforeAll/Each, after...) and tests registred - assigned to queues.

Suits are subsequently executed.

If you log all functions in test, you can see running order (http://plnkr.co/edit/kxX5TAwHOqRRMFjvE5FZ?p=preview)

```
describe("xyz", function() {
  console.log("describe xyz - start");

  var d;
  beforeAll(function(done) {
    console.log("beforeAll");
    setTimeout(function() {
      d = 1234;
      done()
    }, 1000);
  });
  describe("some scenario", function() {
    console.log("describe some scenario - start");

    var d2;
    // d value is undefined here 
    beforeEach(function() {
      console.log("beforeEach");
      d2 = d;
    })

    it("spec1", function() {
      console.log("spec1");
      // it is waiting until beforeAll function is done        
      expect(d).toBe(1234);
    });
    it("spec2", function() {
      console.log("spec2");

      expect(d2).toBe(1234);
    });

    console.log("describe some scenario - end");
  });

  console.log("describe xyz - end");
});
```

-

```
describe xyz - start
describe some scenario - start
describe some scenario - end
describe xyz - end
beforeAll
beforeEach
spec1
beforeEach
spec2
```

This means all your executable code should be inside functions before*/after* or it.